# Reading first byte from a stream in Golang

Tags: go

I have the following function in Golang:

```golang
func ReadFromStdinIfAvailable(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(args) == 0 {
        r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        firstByte, err := r.Peek(1)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if len(firstByte) == 0 {
            cmd.Println(userstrings.NoFilenameProvidedErrorString)
            return nil, errors.New(userstrings.NoFilenameProvidedErrorString)
        }

        var bytesResult []byte
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            // Read from stdin - allocate a buffer to read into
            bytesResult = append(bytesResult, scanner.Bytes()...)
        }
        return bytesResult, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New(userstrings.NoStdInProvidedErrorString)
}
```

It's a very small amount of data (<10 MB to be sure). However, the data should be there from the first read - if it's not, there's an error.

However, when i do this, it hangs on `scanner.Scan()` which is, to be expected, it's a stream.

How can I peek into the `os.Stdin` stream to see if there's any data there before I start reading it?

Comment: [`bufio.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader)? (also note you are using the `Scanner` incorrectly, you must check the return value. See the example in the docs https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#example-Scanner-Lines)

Comment: Yup, fixed that and tried another path... still no joy.

Comment: The only way to attempt to "peek" at a stream is to buffer it, and that's exactly what `bufio.Reader` can do. There is no way to synchronously check if there _will_ be data available at some point, you can only attempt to read from stdin.

Comment: The issue is that if there's NO content in the stream, it just hangs. I'm ok with synchronous/blocking - i just want to bail out if there's NO content when i get to this point in the program.

Comment: Data coming in on stdin must be coming from a concurrent process, which means there's no way to guarantee that the data is not delayed in some way, due to process scheduling, kernel buffering, etc, so there must be an implied "wait for data" in that request. You can choose to exit with an error after a certain amount of time if you'd like, but short of dropping down to select/poll syscalls, you cannot immediately check if there is data available.

Comment: I guess exit with an error it is after a time (how short is too short? like could we virtually guarantee a byte on stdin after 100 ms? 400ms? 2s?). VIRTUALLY guarantee is fine - it's not a critical process at this point and the user could restart it. 

If you'd like to write an answer, happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i ended up doing - if this helps anyone (would love for someone to do this better):

```golang
func ReadFromStdinIfAvailable(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(args) == 0 {
        r := bufio.NewReader(RootCmd.InOrStdin())
        var bytesResult []byte
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)

        // buffered channel of dataStream
        dataStream := make(chan []byte, 1)

        // Run scanner.Bytes() function in it's own goroutine and pass back it's
        // response into dataStream channel.
        go func() {
            for scanner.Scan() {
                dataStream <- scanner.Bytes()
            }
            close(dataStream)
        }()

        // Listen on dataStream channel AND a timeout channel - which ever happens first.
        timedOut := false
        select {
        case res := <-dataStream:
            bytesResult = append(bytesResult, res...)
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(10) * time.Millisecond): //nolint:gomnd // 10ms timeout
            timedOut = true
        }

        if timedOut {
            cmd.Println(userstrings.NoFilenameProvidedErrorString)
            return nil, errors.New(userstrings.NoFilenameProvidedErrorString)
        }
        for scanner.Scan() {
            bytesResult = append(bytesResult, scanner.Bytes()...)
        }

        return bytesResult, nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("should not be possible, args should be empty")
}
```